# In django, how to get all data with exact foreign key? example, get all posts with foreign key = 1 or 2 or

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Hello im new to django and this is my model and I have 2 tables "auth_user" table and "blog_post" table. Inside blog_post table I have a column called "author_id" which is the foreign key between "blog_post" table and "auth_user" table. The question is how can i get all posts from "blog_post" table when foreign key = 1 or 2 or 3 or.. etc. Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant that you wanted to filter by the author, then what you can do is provide the `author_id` as a query parameter on your request, and have the view serving the request filter by the author.

```
Post.objects.filter(author_id=author_id)
```

Comment: Hi sir where should i put that line of code in? Do i have to put it in my Post model?

Comment: You should put the line of code in whatever view is processing the request for blog posts and condition it on the `author_id` query parameter being present in the request.